# data not fetch in php json web api

Tags: php, mysql, json

```
<?php 

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET');

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET')
    {

        $username  = $_GET['username'];
        $status  = $_GET['status'];

        require_once('dbConnect.php');

        if(!empty($username))
        {

            if(empty($status))
            {

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM ticketdetails WHERE (Status != 'Close' or Status != 'H/W_prob')  
        and cancel !='ok' and  person='".$username."'";
            }            
            else
            {
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ticketdetails WHERE   cancel !='ok' 
                    and status= '".$status."' and person='".$username."'";
            }
        $r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

        $result = array();


        while($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r))
        {
            $a[]=$res;

            $result['data']=$a;

        }

        }
        else{
    $result['status'] = "false";
            }

        echo json_encode($result);

        mysqli_close($con);


    }
```

when I check this api I got empty result in output , I have Two server one live and test this api work properly on test server and also locally on wamp but when I upload this script into live I show empty result anything wrong or what i cant understand.....

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious thing to do is check that you have synced the databases so that there are indeed results to be returned on the "live" server... Could there be an empty result because the database/tables aren't populated as they should be?

Comment: database not  sync and table value record more than 50 thousand @Alister Cameron

Comment: $result = array();    
            //echo $result;
            
            foreach ($r as $row) 
                                 {
                    $result['data'] = array($row);
                                 
                                 }} 
when use foreach than shows only one row result show not all rows